# How can I feed a lexer bytes of data at a time?

Tags: c, bison, lex

I am trying to adapt a lexer + parser into a streaming interface in my system which has the following interface:

```c
bool writeData(stream *obj, char *data, size_t length); //lets the stream know of data coming from upstream so that it prepare it to be read from downstream
void read(stream *obj, char *data, size_t length); //read the processed data
size_t readLengthAvailable(stream *obj); //return the amount of data available to be read
```

I have a grammar which is implemented with flex + bison as a re-entrant scanner, but the problem that i have is that there doesnt seem to be an interface to feed the lexer pieces of data at a time.

```
[ \t]   ; // ignore all whitespace
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+  {yylval->fval = atof(yytext); return T_FLOAT;}
[0-9]+      {yylval->ival = atoi(yytext); return T_INT;}
\n      {return T_NEWLINE;}
"+"     {return T_PLUS;}
"-"     {return T_MINUS;}
"*"     {return T_MULTIPLY;}
"/"     {return T_DIVIDE;}
"("     {return T_LEFT;}
")"     {return T_RIGHT;}
```

```
calculation: line { *(int*)out = $1; $$ = $1; YYACCEPT ; }
;

line: T_NEWLINE
    | mixed_expression T_NEWLINE { $$ = (int)$1; }
    | expression T_NEWLINE { $$ = $1; }
    | T_QUIT T_NEWLINE { printf("bye!\n"); exit(0); }
;

mixed_expression: T_FLOAT                        { $$ = $1; }
      | mixed_expression T_PLUS mixed_expression     { $$ = $1 + $3; }
      | mixed_expression T_MINUS mixed_expression    { $$ = $1 - $3; }
      | mixed_expression T_MULTIPLY mixed_expression { $$ = $1 * $3; }
      | mixed_expression T_DIVIDE mixed_expression   { $$ = $1 / $3; }
      | T_LEFT mixed_expression T_RIGHT      { $$ = $2; }
      | expression T_PLUS mixed_expression       { $$ = $1 + $3; }
      | expression T_MINUS mixed_expression      { $$ = $1 - $3; }
      | expression T_MULTIPLY mixed_expression   { $$ = $1 * $3; }
      | expression T_DIVIDE mixed_expression     { $$ = $1 / $3; }
      | mixed_expression T_PLUS expression       { $$ = $1 + $3; }
      | mixed_expression T_MINUS expression      { $$ = $1 - $3; }
      | mixed_expression T_MULTIPLY expression   { $$ = $1 * $3; }
      | mixed_expression T_DIVIDE expression     { $$ = $1 / $3; }
      | expression T_DIVIDE expression       { $$ = $1 / (float)$3; }
;

expression: T_INT               { $$ = $1; }
      | expression T_PLUS expression    { $$ = $1 + $3; }
      | expression T_MINUS expression   { $$ = $1 - $3; }
      | expression T_MULTIPLY expression    { $$ = $1 * $3; }
      | T_LEFT expression T_RIGHT       { $$ = $2; }
;
```

currently my code to feed data to the parser looks like:

```c
    FILE* yyin = stdin;
    int result = 0;

    yyscan_t scanner;
    yy_lex_init(&scanner);
    do {
        result = 0;
        char *line = NULL;
        size_t size = 0;
        if (getline(&line, &size, stdin) == -1) {
            printf("No line\n");
            fflush(0);
            continue;
        }
        yy_scan_bytes(line, size - 2, scanner); // - 2 to remove CRLF
        int parseResult = yy_parse(scanner, &result);
        printf("[Result (%d)]: %d\n", parseResult, result);
        fflush(0);
    } while(!feof(yyin));
```

however when I try to do things like "1 +  CRLF" followed by "1" i would expect to get error followed by 2, but I get syntax error followed by 1.

```
1    +     1
[Result (0)]: 2
1 +
Parse error: syntax error
[Result (1)]: 0
1
[Result (0)]: 1
```

Is there any way to get flex to pick up where it left off?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you use `yywrap()`?  Your parser gets a first packet of data, and doles out the data one byte at a time.  When it's all gone, `yywrap()` is called to see if there's more data, so you check and act accordingly.  Your grammar may have issues, though — you'll need to know when it's recognized something complete, and then go back to recognize the next chunk of data, repeating ad nauseam, or something similar.

Comment: The problem with yywrap is that it doesnt let me say: "i dont have any more bytes right now, but will later" yywrap will also reset the state of the lexer if i understood the docs correctly

Comment: You can simply not return until there will be more data — unless the grammar needs to know about 'no more at the moment' somehow.  And yes, it might well reset the state.  If it's no help, sorry.  It was just an idea that might have been relevant.  But there was a reason for not making it an answer; I wasn't sure it was on the right track for you.  I'm not sure what else to suggest.

Comment: Thanks for trying, yeah, the problem is that the stream api only notifies more data by calling the callback meaning that if the previous callback simply didnt return the thread isnt available to call the callback again with the new data.

Comment: Unrelated: you're not using `getline` correctly. The `size` argument is the current size of the allocation, which is often much larger than the amount of space actually used by the line just read because `getline` does not normally shrink the allocation when a short line is read. You must use the return value from `getline` to know how many valid characters were read. (I'm working on an actual answer but it might take a while.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a comment:

> *The problem is that the stream api only notifies more data by calling the callback meaning that if the previous callback simply didnt return the thread isnt available to call the callback again with the new data*

This comment suggests that the lexing is being done in the context of the callback. The callback must process all of the bytes; there won't be another callback until that callback returns.

Lex (and Yacc) cannot be used in this way. You have to build either a blocking API on top of this input mechanism (wait on some semaphore that his hit by the callback), or else use polling (spin in a loop with some sleep until the API indicates bytes are available).

With Lex and Yacc, it is quite difficult to continue parsing on predictable chunks of input, such that `yyparse` returns in between them. For example, if you want it so that scanning each top-level definition in a language requires a separate `yyparse` call. Hacks are required to ensure that the parsing can continue where the previous call left off.

If the input is arbitrarily divided into chunks provided by some callback that don't follow any syntactic boundaries, forget it.

Comment: Your comment gave me the following idea: could I buffer the stream before this and then call parse on the same buffered stream which accumulates the data until parse succeeds at which point ill advance the buffer by the amount that parse parsed?

Comment: @chacham15 You likely can, and you will likely have the most success if you either buffer everything, or your buffering system is able to do enough superficial lexical analysis to at least recognize major syntactic divisions that can be handled cleanly by separate `yyparse` calls. Of course, the whole approach assumes that the parsing doesn't have to be timely, or drive some sort of feedback events that generate the input itself.